# Spring managed vs non-managed beans

Tags: spring, containers, autowired

I have a simple Result data holder object that gets returned from a method.

I'm confused on what the right way of using or creating this object using Spring boot.

1. Should this class be marked with @Component annotation?
2. Can I just create this object using 'new Result()' or should I autowire and use it?
3. If I use 'new Result()' then this instance will not be managed by Spring. Is that understanding correct? What are the advantages or disadvantages of managed vs non-managed beans.

Thanks,
Sudha

Comment: Your question is a bit short on detail to offer more specific guidance, so I'll provide some general info.  Spring-managed beans are typically (though not always) stateless, and by default are singletons (though this can be configured differently).  Spring manages the lifecycle.  Perhaps a better question is why do you think it should be spring-managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I use 'new Result()' then this instance will not be managed by Spring. Is that understanding correct? What are the advantages or disadvantages of managed vs non-managed beans.

Well the greatest difference is the *Inversion Of Control* IoC (aka *Dependency Injection* DI). If `Result` is managed by spring, you can autowire other spring beans (like services, components, repositories and so on) Moreover you can autowire the `Result` bean in other spring beans. More details can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core)

> Can I just create this object using 'new Result()' or should I autowire and use it?

Well it depends on your scenario. For example if you have a JSON response in a Spring controller, well in this case it's better to use a classic POJO and create it because it depends on your business logic.
On the other side id your bean is a kind of service who can be used in other points of your project because it offers some methods, well in this case I guess it's good to autowire it and make it as a spring bean

> Should this class be marked with @Component annotation?

Well as I said earlier it depends on your scenario. In the case you described (result of a method) maybe it's better to use a classical POJO. But you didn't provide enough information

Comment: Thanks Angelo. This class has no behavior. It just holds the result of a method and from your reply it appears I can just make it a POJO.